# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS when attempting to delete LWC from org with destructiveChanges.xml

Tags: deployment, insufficient-privileges, destructivechanges.xml, deployment-api, deployment-error

I am attempting to delete an LWC from a developer org, as the system admin.  I had the LWC in a managed package, and have the ability to remove it.  However, when I try to delete the LWC with destructiveChanges.xml, I receive the deployment error:

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS: insufficient access rights on cross-reference
> id

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I have had support enable component deletion from packages for the org, and I am able to remove the component from the package via the UI.

Comment: Is the org you are attempting to delete from the packaging org, or an org in which your managed package is installed?

Comment: @DavidReed it is the packaging org.

Comment: Have you had Salesforce support turn on the ability to delete managed components? Note that you may need to follow the [two-stage deletion process](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_managed_component_deletion.htm) to avoid breaking package upgrades.

Comment: @DavidReed yes, sir!

Comment: I'm not certain - this error is super unhelpful, of course! - but I _think_ I've seen this before and it means there's a reference somewhere else in your metadata to that LWC. It's expected that you'd be able to remove it from the package in the UI, but deletion should behave the same through any channel.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidReed, I will do another crawl through the org to make sure all references are deleted.